# Do the creatures entering the battlefield via Strefan, Maurer Progenitor's ability count as being cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So this is the situation:

I used the ability of [Strefan, Maurer Progenitor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Strefan%2C%20Maurer%20Progenitor) to put vampire cards onto the battlefield, sacrificing 2 blood tokens.

I use this to put [Cordial Vampire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cordial%20Vampire) in the battlefield.

Did I cast Cordial Vampire?

Answer (score 8):

You did not cast him. Casting a spell is a particular process, described in rule 601, of putting a card onto the stack, paying its costs, and letting it resolve.